# Trying to make a new environment through conda, but loading too slow

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to create a new virtual environment through conda and am using this code

```
conda create -n new_env python=3.8
```

However, when I try to run this, the kernel just continues to execute and never completes. I have restarted my computer three times now and this has not helped.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: _However, when I try to run this, the kernel just continues to execute and never completes._ How long did you wait?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the following to update your anaconda environment before creating a new environment:

```
conda update conda
```

Comment: okay I just did that, but the create new env command is still not working.

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past and the update conda worked for me. Perhaps try just creating an empty environment with: conda create -n new_env without the python=3.8 and see if that works